# How to strongly factorize code unit testing all parameters of a bunch of functions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, templates

I have a bunch of functions, used to customize an algorithm parameters. Functions are getting a different count of parameters of different types (some standard: `double` or `int`, other custom classes giving access to `double` or `int` values at some point through getters).

All algorithm parameters must be inside valid bounds ([min,max]). I need to write a unit test to make sure the bound checking for every parameter of every function is coded correctly (reach 100% code coverage).

Here is my MCVE:

**Code to be tested:**

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object( double value ) : value( value ) {}
    inline const double& getValue() const { return value; }
private:
    double value;
};

static const double minA = 0;
static const double maxA = 100;
static const int minB = 10;
static const int maxB = 20;
static const Object minC = Object( 23.0 );
static const Object maxC = Object( 29.0 );

bool func1( double a )
{
    if ( a < minA )
        return false;
    else if ( a > maxA )
        return false;

    // do something
    return true;
}

bool func2( int b, const Object& c )
{
    if ( b < minB )
        return false;
    else if ( b > maxB )
        return false;
    else if ( c.getValue() < minC.getValue() )
        return false;
    else if ( c.getValue() > maxC.getValue() )
        return false;

    // do something
    return true;
}
```

**Example of test that has to be factorized:**

```
double getValidValue( const std::pair<double,double>& minmax ) { return minmax.first + (minmax.second-minmax.first)/2; }
int getValidValue( const std::pair<int,int>& minmax ) { return minmax.first + (minmax.second-minmax.first)/2; }
Object getValidValue( const std::pair<Object,Object>& minmax ) { return Object( minmax.first.getValue() + (minmax.second.getValue()-minmax.first.getValue())/2); }

double getInvalidLowerValue( const std::pair<double,double>& minmax ) { return minmax.first - 1; }
int getInvalidLowerValue( const std::pair<int,int>& minmax ) { return minmax.first - 1; }
Object getInvalidLowerValue( const std::pair<Object,Object>& minmax ) { return Object( minmax.first.getValue() - 1); }

double getInvalidUpperValue( const std::pair<double,double>& minmax ) { return minmax.second + 1; }
int getInvalidUpperValue( const std::pair<int,int>& minmax ) { return minmax.second + 1; }
Object getInvalidUpperValue( const std::pair<Object,Object>& minmax ) { return Object( minmax.second.getValue() + 1); }

int main ()
{
    // valid cases:
    assert( func1( getValidValue( std::make_pair(minA,maxA) ) ) );
    assert( func2( getValidValue( std::make_pair(minB,maxB) ), getValidValue( std::make_pair(minC,maxC) ) ) );

    // func1 out of bound cases:
    assert( !func1( getInvalidLowerValue( std::make_pair(minA,maxA) ) ) );
    assert( !func1( getInvalidUpperValue( std::make_pair(minA,maxA) ) ) );

    // func2 out of bound cases:
    // two tests won't offer a 100% code coverage!
    //assert( !func2( getInvalidLowerValue( std::make_pair(minB,maxB) ), getInvalidLowerValue( std::make_pair(minC,maxC) ) ) );
    //assert( !func2( getInvalidUpperValue( std::make_pair(minB,maxB) ), getInvalidUpperValue( std::make_pair(minC,maxC) ) ) );

    // func2, first param out of bound cases
    assert( !func2( getInvalidLowerValue( std::make_pair(minB,maxB) ), getValidValue( std::make_pair(minC,maxC) ) ) );
    assert( !func2( getInvalidUpperValue( std::make_pair(minB,maxB) ), getValidValue( std::make_pair(minC,maxC) ) ) );
    // func2, second param out of bound cases
    assert( !func2( getValidValue( std::make_pair(minB,maxB) ), getInvalidLowerValue( std::make_pair(minC,maxC) ) ) );
    assert( !func2( getValidValue( std::make_pair(minB,maxB) ), getInvalidUpperValue( std::make_pair(minC,maxC) ) ) );

    return (0);
}
```

Note that:

- I use `assert` to simplify the MCVE (I actually use CPPUnit library and `CPPUNIT_ASSERT` macro).
- Calling a function with all parameters invalid won't reach 100% code coverage: As `func2` checks all parameters in different boolean evaluation, having both parameters invalid will not reach code checking second parameter. A function with `n` parameters needs `1+2*n` calls to be fully tested.
- Modifying the way functions check the input parameters (by having one and only one if statement) to make it easier to reach 100% code coverage is not acceptable (the algorithm is used in a medical device and our goal is to be user every bound of every parameter is tested, no matter how the code is written).

As we have many functions (~20) all with lots of parameters (from 1 to 5), I'd like to ideally end up with a fully factorized solution where the core test code would be:

```
int main()
{
    testFunc( &func1, /* give parameter bounds min/max for every parameter of func1 */ );
    testFunc( &func2, /* give parameter bounds min/max for every parameter of func2 */ );
}
```

I tried to use variadic templates here (thought it could help), but I'm not sure this will work and could not find out how to write the `testFunc` function (specially how to iterate over the arguments and how to have a variable `1+2*n` function calls statements, n being the number of arguments...).

Here is what I have so far (not much...and it does not compile), if one wants to use this as a start. But answers with a completely different approach is perfectly acceptable.

```
template <typename ...Args> void testFunc( bool (*func)( Args ... ), const std::pair<Args...,Args...>& args )
{
     assert( (*func)( /* all getValidValue( args ) ... */ );
     for ( arg : args )
     {
         assert( !(*func)( /* all getValidValue but one getInvalidLowerValue */ );
         assert( !(*func)( /* all getValidValue but one getInvalidUpperValue */ );
     }
}

int main()
{
    testFunc( &func1, std::make_pair( minA, maxA ) );
    testFunc( &func2, std::make_pair( minB, maxB ), std::make_pair( minC, maxC ) );
}
```

Note: Solutions using `boost` are acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 implementation could look as follows:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

// CODE TO BE TESTED:

class Object
{
public:
    Object( double value ) : value( value ) {}
    inline const double& getValue() const { return value; }
private:
    double value;
};

static const double minA = 0;
static const double maxA = 100;
static const int minB = 10;
static const int maxB = 20;
static const Object minC = Object( 23.0 );
static const Object maxC = Object( 29.0 );

bool func1( double a )
{
    std::cout << "Calling func1(" << a << ")" << std::endl;
    if ( a < minA )
        return false;
    else if ( a > maxA )
        return false;

    // do something
    return true;
}

bool func2( int b, const Object& c )
{
    std::cout << "Calling func2(" << b << "," << c.getValue() << ")" << std::endl;
    if ( b < minB )
        return false;
    else if ( b > maxB )
        return false;
    else if ( c.getValue() < minC.getValue() )
        return false;
    else if ( c.getValue() > maxC.getValue() )
        return false;

    // do something
    return true;
}

// TESTING CODE:

// integer_sequence implementation

template <class T, T... Vs>
struct integer_sequence { };

template <class T, class, class, class = integer_sequence<T>, class = integer_sequence<T, 0>, class = void>
struct make_integer_sequence_impl;

template <class T, T ICV1, T... Res, T... Pow>
struct make_integer_sequence_impl<T, std::integral_constant<T, ICV1>, std::integral_constant<T, 0>, integer_sequence<T, Res...>, integer_sequence<T, Pow...>, typename std::enable_if<(ICV1 > 0)>::type>: make_integer_sequence_impl<T, std::integral_constant<T, ICV1/2>, std::integral_constant<T, ICV1%2>, integer_sequence<T, Res...>, integer_sequence<T, Pow..., (Pow + sizeof...(Pow))...>> { };

template <class T, T ICV1, T... Res, T... Pow>
struct make_integer_sequence_impl<T, std::integral_constant<T, ICV1>, std::integral_constant<T, 1>, integer_sequence<T, Res...>, integer_sequence<T, Pow...>, void>: make_integer_sequence_impl<T, std::integral_constant<T, ICV1/2>, std::integral_constant<T, ICV1%2>, integer_sequence<T, Pow..., (Res + sizeof...(Pow))...>, integer_sequence<T, Pow..., (Pow + sizeof...(Pow))...>> { };

template <class T, class Res, class Pow>
struct make_integer_sequence_impl<T, std::integral_constant<T, 0>, std::integral_constant<T, 0>, Res, Pow, void> {
   using type = Res;
};

template <class T, T V>
using make_integer_sequence = typename make_integer_sequence_impl<T, std::integral_constant<T, V/2>, std::integral_constant<T, V%2>>::type;

template <size_t V>
using make_index_sequence = make_integer_sequence<size_t, V>;

template <size_t... V>
using index_sequence = integer_sequence<size_t, V...>;

// end of integer_sequence implementation

// helper functions to generate valid/invalid inputs:

// TODO: possibly return values randomly offseted?
double getValidValue( const std::pair<double,double>& minmax ) { return minmax.first + (minmax.second-minmax.first)/2; }
int getValidValue( const std::pair<int,int>& minmax ) { return minmax.first + (minmax.second-minmax.first)/2; }
Object getValidValue( const std::pair<Object,Object>& minmax ) { return Object( minmax.first.getValue() + (minmax.second.getValue()-minmax.first.getValue())/2); }

double getInvalidLowerValue( const std::pair<double,double>& minmax ) { return minmax.first - 1; }
int getInvalidLowerValue( const std::pair<int,int>& minmax ) { return minmax.first - 1; }
Object getInvalidLowerValue( const std::pair<Object,Object>& minmax ) { return Object( minmax.first.getValue() - 1); }

double getInvalidUpperValue( const std::pair<double,double>& minmax ) { return minmax.second + 1; }
int getInvalidUpperValue( const std::pair<int,int>& minmax ) { return minmax.second + 1; }
Object getInvalidUpperValue( const std::pair<Object,Object>& minmax ) { return Object( minmax.second.getValue() + 1); }

// end of helper functions to generate valid/invalid inputs:

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t, class = make_index_sequence<N>>
struct TestFuncImplInnerLoop;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t J, std::size_t... Is>
struct TestFuncImplInnerLoop<N, J, index_sequence<Is...>> {
    template <class Func, class Tup>
    int operator()(Func func, const std::string& funcName, Tup &tup) {
        std::cout << "Calling " << funcName << " with argument #" << J+1 << " lower than lower bound:" << std::endl;
        assert(!(*func)((J == Is)?getInvalidLowerValue(std::get<Is>(tup)):getValidValue(std::get<Is>(tup))...));
        std::cout << "Calling " << funcName << " with argument #" << J+1 << " greater than upper bound:" << std::endl;
        assert(!(*func)((J == Is)?getInvalidUpperValue(std::get<Is>(tup)):getValidValue(std::get<Is>(tup))...));
        return 0;
    }
};

template <std::size_t N, class = make_index_sequence<N>> 
struct TestFuncImpl;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct TestFuncImpl<N, index_sequence<Is...>> {
    template<class Func, class Tup>
    void operator()(Func func, const std::string& funcName, Tup &tup) {
        std::cout << "Calling " << funcName << " with valid arguments:" << std::endl;
        assert((*func)(getValidValue(std::get<Is>(tup))...));
        int falseAsserts[sizeof...(Is)] = { TestFuncImplInnerLoop<N, Is>{}(func, funcName, tup)... };
        (void)falseAsserts;
    }
};

template <class... Args>
void testFunc(bool (*func)(Args...), const std::string& funcName, std::pair<Args, Args>&&... args) {
    auto argsTup = std::make_tuple(args...);
    std::cout << std::endl << "Testing " << funcName << ":" << std::endl;
    TestFuncImpl<sizeof...(Args)>{}(func, funcName, argsTup);
}

// wrapper needed because testFunc can't call function taking const ref as arguments, they need to pass parameters by copy
bool func2Wrapper( int b, Object c )
{
    return func2( b, c );
}

int main() {
    testFunc( &func1, "func1", std::make_pair( minA, maxA ) );
    testFunc( &func2Wrapper, "func2", std::make_pair( minB, maxB ), std::make_pair( minC, maxC ) );
}
```

This works like a charm (OP edit) and outputs:

```
Testing func1:
Calling func1 with valid arguments:
Calling func1(50)
Calling func1 with argument #1 lower than lower bound:
Calling func1(-1)
Calling func1 with argument #1 greater than upper bound:
Calling func1(101)

Testing func2:
Calling func2 with valid arguments:
Calling func2(15,26)
Calling func2 with argument #1 lower than lower bound:
Calling func2(9,26)
Calling func2 with argument #1 greater than upper bound:
Calling func2(21,26)
Calling func2 with argument #2 lower than lower bound:
Calling func2(15,22)
Calling func2 with argument #2 greater than upper bound:
Calling func2(15,30)
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UBaQSKu1N8v3uRcu)

The code need refactor to apply const reference on Objects cause now it demands use Object by value...

Comment: Nice. Can this be adapted to work with complex Object arguments too? Or is it impossible?

Comment: I think so but I don't really know how to interpret the interval for `Object`. Also it has to be stated it is c++14 approach and the migration to c++11 won't be so easy as in c++11 there is no generic lambdas the significant part of the approach...

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck with C++11. However, I forgot to mention that I also use boost. Maybe boost::bind could help.

Comment: @jpo38 changed the code to be c++11 compliant (no boost required). Sorry for deletion but I found bug in the answer and didn't have a time to repair it earlier...

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand your code but it apparently works....;-). I'll have to read this many times before I fully understand it....The refactoring requested is not a problem (can still write a wrapper function taking objects by copy and calling the original function to be tested)!

Comment: Don't forget to change getValid/getInvalid to generate some **random** value from range / out of range...

Comment: Edited your post to make the code more verbose and show it does what's requested by showing the output. I'll add some randomization when implementing that! Thanks again!